# mock-fs test fails in jest when console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, jestjs, fs

For some strange reason when I try to `console.log` within a [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) `test` using [mock-fs](https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs) it fails, I have no clue why this is happening.

Is there as specific reason this is happening? How can I prevent it?

[Example on repl.it here:](https://repl.it/repls/SilkyBrownEquations)

```
import fs from 'mz/fs'
import mockFs from 'mock-fs'

beforeEach(async () => {
  mockFs({
    '/dir': {
      '.pkgrc': JSON.stringify([])
    }
  })
})

afterEach(async () => {
  mockFs.restore()
})

test('readdir callback', (done) => {
  fs.readdir('/dir', (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err
    expect(res).toEqual(['.pkgrc'])
    done()
  })
})

test('readdir promise', async () => {
  const res = await fs.readdir('/dir')
  expect(res).toEqual(['.pkgrc'])
})

test('readdir promise', async () => {
  const res = await fs.readdir('/dir')
  console.log('hi')
  expect(res).toEqual(['.pkgrc'])
})
```

Here's the specific error:

```
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/home/runner/node_modules/callsites'

      at Binding.<anonymous> (node_modules/mock-fs/lib/binding.js:1060:13)
      at maybeCallback (node_modules/mock-fs/lib/binding.js:42:17)
      at Binding.Object.<anonymous>.Binding.lstat (node_modules/mock-fs/lib/binding.js:1057:10)
      at _callee4$ (test.js:91:19)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
      at step (test.js:13:191)
      at test.js:13:361
```

Comment: https://github.com/tschaub/mock-fs/issues/234

Comment: i am also trying to test the logger using jest , can you check this one any help is appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250372/logger-implementation-using-winston-morgan-and-winston-daily-rotate-file